# htaccess redirect to new domain with path and parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all traffic for one folder to a new domain. The setup is as follows:

- original site has a folder "admin" with a .htaccess file (see my rewrite rule below)
- all traffic should go to another site
- path and parameters should be preserved

I made the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     (.*)      http://admin.testsite.com/admin/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works for parameters, but not for the path. The following url won't redirect:

```
www.oldsite.com/admin/account/?test=3
```

How can I get this url to redirect to `admin.testsite.com/admin/account/?test=3`?

---

NB: In the root there is another .htaccess with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /users/index\.php\?file=(.+)&group=(.+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^users/index\.php$ /users/%1/%2\.html? [L,R=301]
```

Can this affect the other rule?

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` looks good, do you have any `RewriteCond`'s that maybe affecting this?

Comment: I've created an empty folder for testing, created the .htaccess with just this in it, preceeded by `RewriteEngine on`. So no conditions.

Comment: Well, that in the root there is another .htaccess with a condition, but I don't see how that would affect this rule. I've updated my question with this.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and restart it and then try your test.

Comment: Nope. the Rewrite rule does not look like correct.

Comment: You got this or you want me to put in answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is official answer.

Question was: "How can get www.oldsite.com/admin/account/?test=3 to redirec to admin.testsite.com/admin/account/?test=3?"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$  http://admin.testsite.com/admin/$1 [R=301,L]            
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the whole domain for the site needs to be changed I found a simple way to redirect ALL requests to new address (including paths and URL parameters):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$  http://www.newsite.com$1 [R=301,L]            
</IfModule>
```